# Worklight CLI build fails. 32-bit issue?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

When using the CLI we get an error

> $ worklight build
>
> /opt/ibm/Worklight-CLI/worklight:
> /opt/ibm/Worklight-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF
> interpreter: No such file or directory

Googling suggests that the CLI is a 32 bit application. Is this true and how to solve this?

Worklight 6.2
Linux itdx-vsptl204 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 21:14:45 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Can you provide more information about what Operating System you are using? Like what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: You can use the following link to see what desktop operating systems are supported http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProductByComponent?deliverableId=968A9CE03A2E11E396F9FC10E99BE807&duComponent=Desktop_606804B0B4CA11E3B58E0C47AA8A6F25

Comment: CentOS 6.5 64bit (all updates done) runlevel 3. It turns out the team were using the CLI on the server when they should have used the ant build scripts on the server. Thanks for your help. No more action needed on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the team were using the CLI on the server when they should have used the ant build scripts on the server. Thanks for your help. No more action needed on this one.